# How do I get a table row to fill to the bottom of the page?

Tags: tables, fill, xltabular

I need a table that will be updated with more rows as the years go on. 
The table itself needs to fill an entire page, with the rows justified to the top of the table. 
How do i get a table to fill an entire page? 
I imagine that i need to stretch a table row to `\vfill` or something like that, but i am unable to get it figured out.

The problem with the below MWE, is that it sets the last row to expand to `\textheight`, but not the remainder of the page height. this results in a large row that interferes with the footer of the page, or jumps the table to the next page.

I have tried using `\vspace*{\fill}` and `\vfill` but to no avail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X}
\hline
test & test & test \\ \hline
test & test & test \\ \hline
test & test & test \\ \hline
& & \\[\textheight] \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The use of `xltabular` suggests that your table should also be able to break across pages. Could you add some info on the desired behaviour reagrind page breaks as well?

Comment: Probably the `tabularht` package gives you the desired result?

Comment: Is there an unknown amount of text that will be before the table?  That would make it more complicated, but if the table will really be the *entire* page, then it does appear that `\begin{tabularht*}{\textheight}` would do the trick.  (Unless you're wanting correctly spaced `\hline`s through the rest of the table.)